# 'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-in-app-utils

I using expo version of react native 0.48.4 (21.0.2 expo) and react-native-in-app-utils@5.6.0. When I link using react-native install react-native-in-app-utils.

Till now I have tried:

1. Manually Linking
2. Deleting node_modules and installing again
3. Including react to the build scheme with parallelized build unchecked
4. Tried to add react to search header path

But still, the stubborn error does not go away.

My pod definition for react is like so:

```
pod 'React',
:path => "../node_modules/react-native",
:subspecs => [
  "Core",
  "BatchedBridge",
  "ART",
  "RCTActionSheet",
  "RCTAnimation",
  "RCTCameraRoll",
  "RCTGeolocation",
  "RCTImage",
  "RCTNetwork",
  "RCTText",
  "RCTVibration",
  "RCTWebSocket",
  "DevSupport",
  "CxxBridge"
]
```

Can some help me?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by installing the lib from cocapods instead of linking it by react native like so:

```
pod ‘react-native-in-app-utils’,
    :git => “https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils”
```

Hope this is helpful to anyone.